# In jQuery if you remove an element will any events on it be removed?

Tags: jquery, event-binding

For example if I have a link with the following event bound to it:

```
$("a.d").bind("click", this, onDelete);
```

And later do:

```
$("a.d").remove();
```

Is that fine? Or does it cause a memory leak and I need to call unbind 1st?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I believe that removing an element will unbind its event handlers. I come to this conclusion from the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) (search for remove) which states that if you want to move an element from one part of the DOM to another that:

```
$("#foo").remove().appendTo("#bar");
```

should be written as

```
$("#foo").appendTo("#bar");
```

to avoid losing the event handlers.

Answer (score 6):

From jQuery docs for remove()

> Removes all matched elements from the
>   DOM. This does NOT remove them from
>   the jQuery object, allowing you to use
>   the matched elements further. Note
>   that this function starting with 1.2.2
>   will also remove all event handlers
>   and internally cached data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, so long as the event was attached WITH jQuery.  If attached with something like "onclick" I don't believe it will.

This article discusses some of that.  It also defines a recursive function to remove all click events for an element and all of its children.  It will cover jQuery click handlers as well as handlers defined with onclick so you're covered.

http://www.computerhowtoguy.com/how-to-use-the-jquery-unbind-method-on-all-child-elements/

```
function RecursiveUnbind($jElement) {
    // remove this element's and all of its children's click events
    $jElement.unbind();
    $jElement.removeAttr('onclick');
    $jElement.children().each(function () {
        RecursiveUnbind($(this));
    });
}
```

To use the function in the previous example we would call the function passing it the “container” div as a jQuery object.

```
RecursiveUnbind($('#container'));
```

Answer (score -2):

For the record, you need not worry about memory leaks in javascript. (chill man, not c++!)

The browser's javascript engine manages all objects, and garbage collects them. When I say objects, that means event-handling-functions too, because functions are also objects in javascript.

Unrelated: I love how everything is an object in javascript :D

Cheers!
jrh

Comment: Not true actually, you can very easily create memory leaks in javascript if you create closures.   Poor event management is one place where memory leaks are common.   Certain js engines are better than others, for example, Chrome's V8 seems to garbage collect the closures properly.   However, Firefox (at least 3.0, haven't tried it with 3.5), and IE can and do have memory leaks in javascript.

Comment: FYI the reason I know this is because I've run into it before (I even asked about it on SO, see this old question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276087/preventing-ajax-memory-leaks)